# Issue with vertical scroll table header

Tags: html, css-tables

Having an issue where my table header is not aligning with my table data correctly, after implementing a vertical scrollbar like so:

```
.tbody{
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: block;
}

.table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: table;
}

.table_header_row{
    display: block;
}
```

Example of how the web page looks with skewed table headers:

[image]

Example of how its supposed to look without the vertical scrollbar:

[image]

Anyway to fix such a problem preferably only using css?

Comment: Can you provide us the whole code? Then we can better help you

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be by setting your header to absolute position

CSS

```
   .yourTableClass {
            position:relative;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
            .yourTableClass thead {
                position:absolute; /*order fixed to freeze the header*/
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                right:0px;
            }
```

HTML:

```
<table class="yourTableClass">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>two</td>
            <td>three</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This still doesn't fix the fact that the header width doesn't fit with the table data width